# Sublime Text & Source Tree cannot see FileDiff in files generated using xml.File and fsObject in Excel VBA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, vba, sublimetext3, atlassian-sourcetree

We are looking at certain .yml files that store translation of a Rails application. For example, the structure of en.yml is as follows:

```
en:
  blog:
    left_navigation:
      list_topic: "Blog topics blah blah"
    articles:
      show:
        by_author: "By %{author}"
  number:
    currency:
      format:
        separator: "."
        delimiter: ","
        format: "%u%n"
  admin:
    blog:
      topics:
        form:
          topic_name: "Topic name"
          topic_parent: "Parent topic"
          save: "Save"
          cancel: "Cancel"
```

As part of our team's translation procedure, we have translators translate changes in Excel, then reexport the new .yml file via macros. The relevant code is:

```
...
FilePathAndName = ExportFolder & ExportLang & ".yml"
...
Set xmlFile = fsObject.createtextfile(FilePathAndName, True, True)
maxline = TargetRange.Rows.Count
i = 1
For Each mCell In TargetRange
    line = mCell.Value
    xmlFile.write line & IIf(i = TargetRange.Rows.Count, vbNullString, vbCrLf)
    i = i + 1
Next mCell
xmlFile.Close
...
```

However, SublimeText cannot see FileDiff when looking at both files together under "Open Folder" interface. Similar, when loaded to Source Tree it says that the 2 files are not identical, but it fails to show the file difference.

We need this file difference to verify that the translations were done with correct syntax. Could somebody help us?

Comment: Is `TargetRange` always only one column wide? If it's more than one column wide then `i = TargetRange.Rows.Count` will be True at some point in the middle of the file and you'll miss out a `vbCrLf` - plus you'll also have an unnecessary `vbCrLf` at the end of the file.

Comment: How is this a rails question?

Comment: Your question is unclear; are you saying that after generating files Sublime thinks they're the same but something else says they're different but no differences show? That sounds like a problem with the line endings changing; Sublime diffs a line at a time (so would show no differences) while source control would see differences but have nothing to show because the changes are to invisible characters.

Comment: @OdatNurd the files are completely different because the translators have added translated content. But neither Sublime Text nor SourceTree can show the difference via +/- lines as they can with other files.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your ideas @Odatnurd and @barrowc
The issue comes from the encoding of the second (destination file). Apparently it needed to be UTF-8. So I just resaved this file in Sublime Text with Encoding = UTF-8 and FileDiff worked again.
[image]

So a final question is, how do I make xml.File and fsObject in Excel VBA save the file in UTF-8 format?